# Rectangle decomposition into rectangle with side of length 1

Tags: geometry

I've read somewhere that it was possible to cut any rectangle into a finite number of pieces and reassemble it into another rectangle with a side of length 1 but I can't see how this is done... Can anyone explain this to me or give me any helpful links?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Search under Bolyai-Gerwien Theorem. (The second guy's name has variable spelling.) The stronger result is proved is that if $A$ and $B$ are polygonal regions with the same area, then $A$ can be cut up into polygonal pieces and reassembled to make $B$. The result you refer to is sometimes a lemma in this proof. The key thing is that a rectangle can be cut up and reassembled to make a square.

Answer (score 0):

Hilbert third problem .
We can cut and resamble **any** poligonal sufaces into another poligonal suface of the **same area**.But the demonstration have many steps.

First cut rectanle $a$x$b$ in a sqare like here
[trasform rectangle in sqare_1](http://sofia.nmsu.edu/~breakingaway/Lessons/R2S/R2S.html) or here [transform rectangle in square_2](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~huberty/math5337/groupe/squarerect.html)
or if you like Youtube [Quadrature: Rectangle to Square With Equal Area](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pjXdjTFhWk) and more in [square from rectangle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtiNWWzP5kk)

Take rectangle of $1$x$(ab)$ and do the same thing.

Now you have $2$ identical sqares but otherwise cut. 
Put one sqare above the other sqare and cut all "intersections".
Now you have all components.